# Perl Oauth2 package

Tags: perl, token, cpan, oauth-2.0

What is the best package to do OAuth2 based authentication.

I basically need to authenticate using a consumer key and secret key to get a consumer, and use a access token and secret to get a token. And then use the consumer and token to get the client to use to make the request?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend CPAN search.  I would stick with Net::OAuth2 (which appears to be being actively developed by the same guy that did Net::OAuth very actively), which contains ::Client and ::WebServer classes.

http://search.cpan.org/search?query=OAuth2&mode=all